# Using index to pull items from an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I have an object with items named and ending in sequential numbers:

`var theobject = { item1:, item2:, item3:, ...etc }`

this method of extracting the objects and used in a for loop does not seem to work. Should this work provided the rest of the function is correct?

`theobject.item+i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like `theobject['item'+i]`.
But you can do something better using jquery foreach so that you can iterate over keys.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's necessary in this this case though, thanks. This works just fine.